# Mongodb, how to get all array's each matching first element in DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a scenario that requires to select ALL element's first return.

What I am currently practicing is using a loop

```
const array_list = await Person.find({});
const results = [];
for (const element in array_list) {
  const temp_result = await Transactions.find({_id: array_list[element]._id}).sort({$natural: -1 }).limit(1);
  results.push(temp_results);
}
```

This works, but I figure out this may slow down the whole process if the database became larger in term of scale, is there anyway to faster this result?

Comment: You can try using the `$lookup` for efficiency - and avoid sending multiple reads to the database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this to use a single db-query for finding the transaction documents by specifying the `$in` [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) where you pass in the the `_id`s of the person `array_list`:

```
const elementIds = array_list.map(elem => elem._id);    
await Transactions.find({_id: { $in: elementIds  }}).sort({$natural: -1 }).limit(1);
```

Above solution still requires two db-reads - if you want to do it in a single query, you can do an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)-query where you `$lookup` the transaction documents for each person (see examples in the doc-page).

Comment: @Wing Shum: Any feedback?